# Acumatica I cannot change aspx screen with ASPX Editor

Tags: acumatica

I need to insert:  **OnDataBound**="grid_RowDataBound"  to a PXGrid.

My issue is, that I cannot make the insert with Acumatica ASPX Editor. As soon as I GENERATE CUSTOMIZATION SCRIPT, the code inserted disappears.

Now, if I edit that aspx screen with VS, I'm able to insert and save my change, but this change is not reflected in the Acumatica screen.

Do I have to compile the changes in VS?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Alfredo

Comment: could be an issue with Acumatica ASPX editor. I have had scenarios in the past where i had to manually enter the  project.xml entry for a page to get it working. I know that doesn't help but look at how the add of another property might update the project.xml and see if manually adding it helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Some aspx page cannot be edited. I too got this same situation in moving tab item to other place in the grid. but it did not allow me to do. So I used java script code to move the tabs.

I dont know whether this works or not.
Try to edit the aspx page in the file editor by adding the page that you want to customize and publish it.
File Editor is the nothing but "file" which you can see left pane of the project Editor

Comment: saikiran, thanks for your response.
I'm not quite sure to understand your suggestion, about 
"Try to edit the aspx page in the file editor by adding the page that you want to customize and publish it. "
Which file editor are you referring to?